# in javascript, string.replace gives Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function superman(){ //some code
var opitem = $("#opinionitem").html();
opitem.replace(":opinionid","valid string");
//more code
}
```

gives Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of null

```
alert(opitem)
```

gives a string alert, not null

opinionitem

```
<div id="opinionitem" opinionid="0" >
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Image Here<img src="" onclick=""></img></td>
            <td>
              <input type="hidden" value="0"/>
              <span id="opinionid">:opinionid</span>
              <span id="opinion">:opinion</span><br/>
              <span id="note">:note</span></br>
              <span id="dateposted">:dateposted</span> - 
              <span id="lastvote">:lastvote</span> - 
              <span id=""lastcomment>:lastcomment</span>

              <button id="deleteopinionbutton" 
                      onclick="deleteopinion(:opinionid)">Delete Opinion</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: Did you verify using a debugger (e.g. firebug) that the error actually happens in the code you posted? Oh, and you need to assign the return value of `replace()` as it does not modify the string it was called on.

Comment: That means that `$("#opinionitem").html()` is returning nothing. There's probably no item on the page with that "id" value.

Comment: Can you show us what `$("#opinioitem")` has?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
opitem=opitem.replace(":opinionid","valid string");
```

solved my problem, thanks thiefmaster

Comment: What was the problem? I can't see any thing different?

Comment: @gdoron .replace method returns replaced string, it does not update the  object instance, therefore I need to assign it to the object insance.

Comment: That said(and known already...) that still doesn't explain why did you get null error.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector doesn't grab any element, thus `html` return null.

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GzNwe/) demo:

```
<div id='first'></div>
alert($('#first').html());  // alert(''); 
alert($('#second').html());​ // alert(null);
```

​